# Change in the HTML table format sent using mutt in outlook

Tags: awk, mutt

Here is my sample html code:

[image: my html code]

when I send this as an email using mutt to my outlook, the output is as follows:
[image: outlook html table]

The command I used is:

mutt -e "my_hdr Content-Type: text/html" -s "Subject: my subject" mymail@outlookmail.com < sampletable.html

In the second table there is some different format. First table is not looking good as well.
If there are more than 2 tables, all the alternate tables are having the same format as second one.

How to make my email look good?
PS: I am generating this sample html table code using awk in a bash script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace ending `<tr>` by closing tr : `</tr>`.

Comment: yeah.. I already made the change and that worked.! :D
Thank you.! :)